# define a c++ template with unknown depth/dimension

Tags: c++, templates

I'd like to write an n-dimensional histogram class. It should be in the form of bins that contains other bins etc.  where each bin contains min and max range, and a pointer to the next dimension bins

a bin is defined like

```
template<typename T>
class Bin {
 float minRange, maxRange;
 vector<Bin<either Bin or ObjectType>> bins;
}
```

This definition is recursive. So in run time the user defines the dimension of the histogram

```
so if its just 1-dimension, then
Bin<Obj>
while 3-dimensions
Bin<Bin<Bin<Obj>>>
```

Is this possible?

Regards

Comment: How are you specifying the number of dimensions? Your pseudo-code is lacking here...

Comment: @K-ballo : That's only part of it; is it passed to the constructor or supplied after construction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly, C++11 has variable length parameter lists for templates. Even without C++11 you can use specialisation, if all your dimensions have the same type:

```
template <typename T, unsigned nest>
struct Bin {
  std::vector<Bin<T, (nest-1)> > bins;
};

template <typename T>
struct Bin<T,0> {
  T content;
};
```

You can only specify the dimension at runtime to a certain degree. If it is bound by a fixed value you can select the appropriate type even dynamically. However, consider using a one-dimensional vector instead of a multi-dimensional jagged vector!

Answer (score 1):

To get the exact syntax you proposed, do:

```
template <typename T>
class Bin
{
    float minRange, maxRange;
    std::vector<T> bins;
};
```

And it should do exactly what you put in your question:

```
Bin< Bin< Bin<Obj> > > bins;
```

To do it dynamically (at runtime), I employed some polymorphism. The example is a bit complex. First, there is a base type.

```
template <typename T>
class BinNode {
public:
    virtual ~BinNode () {}
    typedef std::shared_ptr< BinNode<T> > Ptr;
    virtual T * is_object () { return 0; }
    virtual const T * is_object () const { return 0; }
    virtual Bin<T> * is_vector() { return 0; }
    const T & operator = (const T &t);
    BinNode<T> & operator[] (unsigned i);
};
```

`BinNode` figures out if the node is actually another vector, or the object.

```
template <typename T>
class BinObj : public BinNode<T> {
    T obj;
public:
    T * is_object () { return &obj; }
    const T * is_object () const { return &obj; }
};
```

`BinObj` inherits from `BinNode`, and represents the object itself.

```
template <typename T>
class Bin : public BinNode<T> {
    typedef typename BinNode<T>::Ptr Ptr;
    typedef std::map<unsigned, std::shared_ptr<BinNode<T> > > Vec;
    const unsigned dimension;
    Vec vec;
public:
    Bin (unsigned d) : dimension(d) {}
    Bin<T> * is_vector() { return this; }
    BinNode<T> & operator[] (unsigned i);
};
```

`Bin` is the vector of `BinNode`'s.

```
template <typename T>
inline const T & BinNode<T>::operator = (const T &t) {
    if (!is_object()) throw 0;
    return *is_object() = t;
}
```

Allows assignment to a `BinNode` if it is actually the object;

```
template <typename T>
BinNode<T> & BinNode<T>::operator[] (unsigned i) {
    if (!is_vector()) throw 0;
    return (*is_vector())[i];
}
```

Allows the `BinNode` to be indexed if it is a vector.

```
template <typename T>
inline BinNode<T> & Bin<T>::operator[] (unsigned i)
{
    if (vec.find(i) != vec.end()) return *vec[i];
    if (dimension > 1) vec[i] = Ptr(new Bin<T>(dimension-1));
    else vec[i] = Ptr(new BinObj<T>);
    return *vec[i];
}
```

Returns the indexed item if it is present, otherwise creates the appropriate entry, depending on the current dimension depth. Adding a redirection operator for pretty printing:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream &
operator << (std::ostream &os, const BinNode<T> &n) {
    if (n.is_object()) return os << *(n.is_object());
    return os << "node:" << &n;
}
```

Then you can use `Bin` like this:

```
int dim = 3;
Bin<float> v(dim);
v[0][1][2] = 3.14;
std::cout << v[0][1][2] << std::endl;
```

It doesn't currently support 0 dimension, but I invite you to try to do it yourself.

Comment: Many thanks, this solution should also work. I like though the solution of "bitmask". its more simple. regards